# NSDateFormatter: how to convert “Sat, 17 Dec 2016 18:56:08 +0100 (GMT+01:00)" to date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have the following string `"Sat, 17 Dec 2016 18:56:08 +0100 (GMT+01:00)” to date?"`

## Update

I remove the last part of string. Then I have the following string: `"Sat, 17 Dec 2016 18:56:08 +0100"`

This is my code:

```
_emailDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_emailDateFormatter setDateFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", nil)];
NSDate* date = [[ParlaMobileUtils sharedInstance].emailDateFormatter dateFromString:@"Sat, 17 Dec 2016 18:56:08 +0100"];
NSString* string_date = [[ParlaMobileUtils sharedInstance].dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

But NSDate is always nil.

Comment: Q: Does `Z` match `+0100 (GMT+01:00)`? A: No.

Comment: @mmaddy I know its wierd but works on python and Java....

Comment: What is the actual format, though? Is the first +0100 promised to be "the offset from GMT without a colon" or could it be something else, like CET? It's likely parsable, but only if you know what the rules actually are. (Personally, I'd just strip it down to the parts you trust, though, like @vadian suggests.)

Comment: @RobNapier So I have to +- hours to the result date manually?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The time zone is in the format. You just need to pick the part of the duplicate time zone you actually trust. My question is what this format actually is saying. That will impact what format configurations you use. Also, for example, is "Dec" promised to be in English, or is it localized? Without knowing that, you can't know how to configure the parser.

Comment: I have updated the question removing the last part of my string. Yes my date is in english.

Answer (score 0):

This is the parser what i was looking for.

```
_emailDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_emailDateFormatter setDateFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", nil)];
[_emailDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[_emailDateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Comment: There is no reason to set the formatter's timezone since the timezone is coming from the string you are parsing.